# Extra characters/bytes in metadata after saving a PNG image

Tags: vb.net, graphics, png, metadata

I am trying to create metadata to be stored in a PNG Image file, depending on the value of a parameter called `sc_status`.

The code is as follows:

```
Dim qualityParam As Object
Dim encoderParams As Object = New Imaging.EncoderParameters(1)
Dim ImgCodec As Imaging.ImageCodecInfo

ImgCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/png")
qualityParam = New Imaging.EncoderParameter(Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth, 32L)
encoderParams.Param(0) = qualityParam

'---
' img_src Image is created here
' file_name String is created here
'---

' Creating the PropertyItem
Dim propit As Imaging.PropertyItem = CType(System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(GetType(Imaging.PropertyItem)), Imaging.PropertyItem)

propit.Id = 270 '0x010E = Image description
propit.Type = 2

If sc_status = 3 Then
    propit.Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HQ")
ElseIf sc_status = 5 Then
    propit.Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("LQ")
Else
    propit.Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("UQ")
End If

' Storing the PropertyItem
img_src.SetPropertyItem(propit)

' Saving png
img_src.Save(file_name, ImgCodec, encoderParams)
```

When I have a look at what is stored in the PNG chunks, I expect to have in byte sequence `[72, 81, 0]` or `[76, 81, 0]` or `[85, 81, 0]`, corresponding to the string `"LQ"`,`"HQ"`,`"UQ"` plus the `vbNullChar` which is automatically added at the end of the PNG chunk.

But for a reason I ignore, I sometimes have a longer byte sequence, e.g. `[72, 81, 28, 8, 1, 0]` which gives - after using `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` - the string:

```
HQ & ChrW(28) & vbBack & ChrW(1) & vbNullChar
```

or sometimes `[72, 81, 22, 8, 1, 0]`, or sometimes `[72, 81, 19, 8, 1, 0]` or sometimes `[72, 81, 23, 8, 1, 0]`.

I don't understand why sometimes extra bytes are added in the metadata during the `img_src.Save()` procedure.
What am I doing wrong? Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PropertyTagImageDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-constant-property-item-descriptions#propertytagimagedescription) is defined as a null-terminated ASCII string (`PropertyTagTypeASCII`).
As described in the Documentation, [PropertyItem.Type PropertyTagTypeASCII](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.type):

> Specifies that `Value` is a null-terminated ASCII string. If you set the
> type data member to ASCII type, you should set the `Len` property to the
> length of the string including the null terminator. For example, the
> string `"Hello"` would have a length of 6.

A few details:

- The `PropertyItem.Value` property stores *data* as a byte array. Even though the Docs refer to an *ASCII string*, storing the bytes of a UTF-8 encoded strings, retrieved calling `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`, is no *forbidden* though. Just terminate the string and set the correct number of bytes stored: as mentioned `Value` store just bytes.
- The `PropertyItem.Len` property **must** be set to the length of the string, so to the length of the byte, thus the length of the `Value` property.

► There's no reason to define the Types as `Object`, as in:

```
Dim qualityParam As Object
Dim encoderParams As Object = New Imaging.EncoderParameters(1)
```

Declare these Types for what they are.

Sample implementation, using UTF-8 encoded strings:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Text

'0x010E = Image description
Dim imageDescriptionPropItem = &H10E
' Property Type 2: null-terminated string
Dim PropertyTagTypeASCII As short = 2

Dim encoderParams As New EncoderParameters(1)
Dim ImgCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().
               FirstOrDefault(Function(enc) enc.FormatID = ImageFormat.Png.Guid)
If ImgCodec Is Nothing Then
    Throw New FormatException("Invalid format")
End If
encoderParams.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth, 32L)

Dim imagePath = [Image Source Path]
Dim imageDestinationPath = [Image Destination Path]
Dim imageSource = Image.FromStream(
    New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(imageSourcePath)), False, False)

Dim propItem As PropertyItem = DirectCast(FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(
    GetType(PropertyItem)), PropertyItem)

propItem.Id = imageDescriptionPropItem 
propItem.Type = PropertyTagTypeASCII

Dim description = String.Empty
Select Case sc_status
    Case 3
        description = "HQ"
    Case 5
        description = "LQ"
    Case 100
        ' Test string, in Russian :)
        description = "Тестовая строка"
    Case Else
        description = "UQ"
End Select

' Length of the string including the terminator: mandatory
propItem.Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(description & ChrW(0))
propItem.Len = propItem.Value.Length

imageSource.SetPropertyItem(propItem)
imageSource.Save(imageDestinationPath, ImgCodec, encoderParams)
```

```
' Load it back, to check what's what
Dim imageEncoded = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(imageDestinationPath)))
Dim propItemSaved = imageEncoded.GetPropertyItem(imageDescriptionPropItem)
Dim descr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(propItemSaved.Value).TrimEnd(ChrW(0))
```