# Extra null Char between characters in metadata encoding a JPG image

Tags: vb.net, graphics, metadata, jpeg, gdi+

This thread is a continuation of [Extra characters/bytes in metadata after saving a PNG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187008/extra-characters-bytes-in-metadata-after-saving-a-png-image)

But I now consider `JPEG`files, not `PNG` files.

I am trying to write metadata depending on the value of a parameter called 'sc_status'. I adapted Jimi's proposal that works very fine with `PNG` files:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Text

'0x9286 = User Comments
Dim imageDescriptionPropItem = &H9286
' Property Type 2: null-terminated string
Dim PropertyTagTypeASCII As short = 2

Dim encoderParams As New EncoderParameters(1)
Dim ImgCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().
               FirstOrDefault(Function(enc) enc.FormatID = ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid)
If ImgCodec Is Nothing Then
    Throw New FormatException("Invalid format")
End If
encoderParams.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 95L)

Dim imagePath = [Image Source Path]
Dim imageDestinationPath = [Image Destination Path]
Dim imageSourcePath = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(imageSourcePath)))

Dim propItem As PropertyItem = DirectCast(FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(
    GetType(PropertyItem)), PropertyItem)

propItem.Id = imageDescriptionPropItem 
propItem.Type = PropertyTagTypeASCII

Dim description = String.Empty
Select Case sc_status
    Case 3
        description = "HQ" & ChrW(0)
    Case 5
        description = "LQ" & ChrW(0)
    Case Else
        description = "UQ" & ChrW(0)
End Select

' Length of the string including the terminator: mandatory
propItem.Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(description)
propItem.Len = propItem.Value.Length

imageSource.SetPropertyItem(propItem)
imageSource.Save(imageDestinationPath, ImgCodec, encoderParams)
```

The metadata check is performed with:

```
Dim imageEncoded = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(imageDestinationPath)))
Dim propItemSaved = imageEncoded.GetPropertyItem(imageDescriptionPropItem)
Dim descr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(propItemNew.Value).TrimEnd(ChrW(0))
```

I expect to have in byte sequence `[72, 81, 0]` or `[76, 81, 0]` or `[85, 81, 0]`. But I get `[72, 0, 81, 0, 0]` or `[76, 0, 81, 0, 0]` or `[85, 0, 81, 0, 0]`. So There is an extra 0 byte between each character, which provides the following strings: `"L" & vbNullChar & "Q" & vbNullChar` and so on.

Why are those zeroes inserted and how to get rid of this?
Why does it work fine with `PNG` images (using Image Description prop item `&H10E`) and not JPEG images (using User Comment prop item `&H9286`)?

Many thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the wrong PropertyItem.Type.
The [PropertyTagExifUserComment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-constant-property-item-descriptions#propertytagexifusercomment) (`0x9286`) defines its Type as `PropertyTagTypeUndefined = 7`, while you're setting it to `PropertyTagTypeASCII = 2`, as the Type related to the `PropertyTagImageDescription` PropertyItem. These Types don't store the data in the same way:

> The character code used in the PropertyTagExifUserComment tag is
> identified based on an ID code in a fixed 8-byte area at the start of
> the tag data area. The unused portion of the area is padded with null
> characters (0). ID codes are assigned by means of registration.
> Because the type is not ASCII, it is not necessary to use a NULL
> terminator.

There's no need to set the null-terminator, but if you do, that's not a problem either.

Unfortunately, the Docs are not straightforward in relation to the `PropertyItem.Type` values. These are defined in `gdiplusimaging.h`. Use the [PropertyItem.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.type) descriptions as reference.

Let's define an enumerator for these PropertyItems Types, to simplify its use:

```
Public Enum PropertyItemType As Short
    PropertyTagTypeByte = 1
    PropertyTagTypeASCII = 2
    PropertyTagTypeShort = 3
    PropertyTagTypeLong = 4
    PropertyTagTypeRational = 5
    PropertyTagTypeUndefined = 7
    PropertyTagTypeSLONG = 9
    PropertyTagTypeSRational = 10
End Enum
```

Thus the code changes in:

```
Dim propTagExifUserComment = &H9286

propItem.Id = propTagExifUserComment
propItem.Type = PropertyItemType.PropertyTagTypeUndefined
' [...]
Dim propItemSaved = imageSaved.GetPropertyItem(propTagExifUserComment)
```

Expect this, the code remains the same.